# How to store a time zone preference under Windows XP AND Vista

Tags: windows, timezone, registry

Between Windows XP and Vista (and server 2003 and 2008) Microsoft have removed the `Index` key from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones` and guess which value we store in our database to record an employee's time zone...

(See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/935369).

What is the best value to use instead? Microsoft seem to advocate using the name of the registry key for the time zone in question (like `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\GMT Standard Time`) but that feels like magic constants to me.

Is there a value that is guaranteed to be unique and fixed across Windows versions, cultures, translations and localisations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems like those magic constants are the best way of identifying those time zones.

In fact, this is exactly what .NET 3.5's [TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx) class [uses](http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2007/06/07/exploring-windows-time-zones-with-system-timezoneinfo-josh-free.aspx) as its Id field.

.NET's docs say that it "is a key string that uniquely identifies a particular time zone." implying that it is not localized.

Comment: OK, that relieves my conscience nicely. Thanks :)